# Show that the matrix of T relative to the basis ${1, x, x^2}$ is

Tags: linear-algebra

T is the application defined by $T(a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2)$ = $a_1x$

Show that the matrix of T relative to the basis ${1, x, x^2}$ is:
$\left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0
    \end{array}
\right]$

Comment: Just apply $T$ to the basis $1,x,x^2$.

Comment: Apply $\;T\;$ on the basis elements and write each outcome as a linear combination of themselves. The coefficients of each line become the matrix's columns. With a little practice I think it is almost immediate.

Answer (score 2):

Every linear transformation can be written in matrix form. Just start with the most general case, i.e.

$$\pmatrix{t_{11} & t_{12} & t_{13} \\ t_{21} & t_{22} & t_{23} \\ t_{31} & t_{32} & t_{33}}$$
with $t_{ij} \in\mathbb R$. Then,

$$T(a_0 + a_1 x + a_2x^2) = (a_0 t_{11} + a_1 t_{12} + a_2 t_{13}) + (a_0 t_{21} + a_1 t_{22} + a_2 t_{23}) \cdot x + (a_0 t_{31} + a_1 t_{32} + a_2 t_{33}) \cdot x^2$$

but we want it to be $T(a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2) = a_1x$. Two polynomials are equal if and only if their coefficients are equal. Hence, we get

$$a_0 t_{11} + a_1 t_{12} + a_2 t_{13} = 0$$
$$a_0 t_{21} + a_1 t_{22} + a_2 t_{23} = a_1$$
$$a_0 t_{31} + a_1 t_{32} + a_2 t_{33} = 0$$
for all $a_0,a_1,a_2 \in \mathbb R$. It follows that all $t_{ij} = 0$ except $t_{22} = 1$. Thus, the matrix of $T$ is

$$\pmatrix{0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0}$$

Answer (score 1):

In the basis $\{ 1,x,x^2\}$, the vector $v=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2$ is represented by the components:
$$v=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_0\\a_1\\a_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$u=a_1x=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\a_1\\0
\end{bmatrix}
$$ 
So you want a matrix $M$ such that:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
m_{11}&m_{12}&m_{13}\\m_{21}&m_{22}&m_{23}\\m_{31}&m_{32}&m_{33}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_0\\a_1\\a_2
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\a_1\\0
\end{bmatrix} \quad \forall a_1,a_2,a_3
$$
a simple inspection shows the result.